# Display Image when image uri on listview is clicked

Tags: android, image, listview, android-listview

I have a fragment with a listview and an imagebutton. The imagebutton is for selecting and attaching images from the phone's gallery to the listview.

Now what I want to do is that, if I click the image uri on my listview, the full view or thumbnail (whichever is much preferable) will pop-up.

What I did was, I set up a dialog with a customize layout with an imageview. Whenever I click on the image uri, the dialog box will appear. But of course, there's no image on it yet.

So how can i display the full view or thumbnail of the image uri on it?

**Fragment:**

```
public class Fragment1 extends Fragment implements OnClickListener {

    ListView lv;
    ArrayList<Uri> array_list = new ArrayList<Uri>();
    ArrayAdapter<Uri> array_adapter;

    final int RQS_LOADIMAGE = 0;

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment, container, false); 

        ImageButton b = (ImageButton) v.findViewById(R.id.button_ai);
        b.setOnClickListener(this);

        array_adapter = new ArrayAdapter<Uri>(getActivity(), android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, array_list);
        lv = (ListView) v.findViewById(R.id.list_ai);
        lv.setAdapter(array_adapter);

        lv.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> a, View v, int position, long id) { 

                LayoutInflater inflater = getActivity().getLayoutInflater();
                View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.image_layout, null);

                AlertDialog.Builder adb = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity());  
                adb.setView(view);
                adb.show(); 
            }
        });
        return v;
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {

        switch (v.getId()) 
        {           
            case R.id.button_ai:
                Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK, android.provider.MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);
                startActivityForResult(intent, RQS_LOADIMAGE);
            break;
        }           
    }

    public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

      if (requestCode == RQS_LOADIMAGE) {

          if(resultCode == MainActivity.RESULT_OK) {
            Uri imageUri = data.getData();
            array_list.add(imageUri);
            array_adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
          }
      }
    }

}
```

**image_layout.xml:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <ImageView 
        android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
        android:contentDescription="@string/desc" />


</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm doing it like this:
1- create new activity
2- go to mainfest and put `android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Dialog"` to your activity and it will be like this

```
<activity
        android:name="package.ShowImage"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_show_image" 
        android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Dialog">
    </activity>
```

3- go to ShowImage.java and change it if you want to be like this:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);//hide title of activity
    setContentView(R.layout.image_layout);
}
```

4- start this activity on click
5- good luck

**Edit:**
For your code,This how it well

```
AlertDialog.Builder adb = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity());  
adb.setView(view);
Bitmap bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(array_list.get(position).toString());
ImageView image = (ImageView) adb.findViewById(R.id.image);
image.setImageBitmap(bmp); 
adb.show();
```

Comment: My problem is, how will the thumbnail or fullview image of the image uri will be displayed.

Comment: @user3012327 I meant you can start dialog easier like that but if you want to control the image view on the dialog do it like this: `ImageView image = (ImageView) adb.findViewById(R.id.image);` . hope this helps

Comment: I did start my dialog with an imageview. My only problem is that how to put the thumbnails or fullview images of the image uri on that imageview

Comment: `Bitmap bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(array_list.get(position));
    
    ImageView image = (ImageView) adb.findViewById(R.id.image);
    image.setImageBitmap(bmp);
    ` put it after `adb.setView(view);` before `adb.show();`

Comment: "decodeFile is not applicable for the arguments uri" my array_list is uri. ArrayList<Uri> array_list = new ArrayList<Uri>(); How can i solved this?

Comment: `array_list.get(position).toString()` I'm sorry I forgot. but when you have simple issue, just google it.